# How is the Forth data stack accessed in assembler?

Tags: assembly, stack, forth, vfxforth

I'm just starting to get into both forth and assembler.

In forth, if I create a word as follows:

`: push5 5 ;`

I have created a word that simply puts 5 on the stack.

If I ask to see the created assembler with:

`see push5`

I get:

```
( 0010D5C0    488D6DF8 )              LEA     RBP, [RBP+-08]
( 0010D5C4    48895D00 )              MOV     [RBP], RBX
( 0010D5C8    BB05000000 )            MOV     EBX, # 00000005
( 0010D5CD    C3 )                    RET/NEXT
( 14 bytes, 4 instructions )
```

I mostly understand the instructions (`[RBP+-08]` has me a bit puzzled) but I'm struggling to understand the context in which this piece of code runs and how exactly it adds 5 to the stack.

Where is forth storing its stack? What format does it take? How is this code adding to the stack just by moving `5` into `EBX`?

Many thanks for any light anyone can shed or any documentation someone can point me to (I've struggled to find something relevant).

Thank you!

EDIT: I'm wondering if it's this:

At any given time, RBP contains the address of the top of the stack (TOS), and the stack is really just a section of memory.

So the first line loads into RBP an address that is 8 bytes greater than the current address in RBP, so that RBP now contains the address where the `5` will go.

The second line copies the contents of RBX to the address that is now stored in RBP and that is the top of stack

Then the third line puts `5` into EBX, the lower 32 bits of RBX.

But now I'm puzzled. If that's it, then how does copying 5 into the EBX register affect what's in the memory location contained in RBP? The copy of RBX into [RBP] doesn't mean that any future changes to RBX (eg copying 5 into EBX) will be reflected in [RBP] does it??

EDIT2: Sorry, missed off details about the implementations. This is VfxForth, on x86_64, linux version.

Comment: For documentation you would have to include the name of the implementation you are looking at. I don't think there is only one The Forth for x86_64. Anyway, the code seems to maintain a separate callstack at RSP and a data stack at RBP with the top value in RBX. The snippet stashed the old value of RBX into the data stack and moved the new value (5) into RBX (EBX ... it is assuming that the upper half of RBX was zero?).

Comment: Oh thank you! Yes, I think I see now. The stack is effectively split, with the top value as you say in RBX, and then the rest of the values in contiguous memory going backwards, with TOS-1 being stored in the address given by [RBP]. (By the way I've read in the intel documentation that moving a value into EBX automatically zeros out the upper bits of RBX, so that makes that call safe) Thanks again for your help. I can go to bed now! XD

Comment: You might like to read https://www.bradrodriguez.com/papers/moving1.htm on low-level implementation techniques for Forth.  There is a section about register allocation, including a discussion of this "top of stack in register" trick.

Answer (score 1):

VFX Forth (like many other modern Forth systems) stores the top of the data stack in a register, and the other stack elements in memory.

See "[Inside the MPE VFX code generator](https://www.mpeforth.com/arena/insidevfx.pdf)" (pdf), page 4:

> **Stack shuffle** 
> In most processor architectures, it is beneficial to keep items in registers. In most VFX implementations, there is a canonical stack representation consisting of the top of the data stack in a register, the other items being indexed from a data stack pointer.

In the example in the question, the top of the data stack is stored in the register `RBX`. Thus, before a new value is placed in `RBX`, the previous value is moved into memory.